# Are $ e^x , \ln (x) ,\cos( x)$ functions of $x$?

Tags: functions

Can we consider $$ e^x ,\, \ln (x) ,\,\cos(x)\cdots $$ as functions of $x$ ?

I mean in a differential equation problem for an example (or in any problem )

Comment: Yes, they are functions of $x$.

Comment: @Robert Israel thanks...

Comment: What made you think they weren't?

Comment: The first time I see a yes/no question in stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you fix an element (let say $x$), and that you write a number that depends on this number (let say $7x^2$ and we call this number $y$, i.e. $y=7x^2$), then the number $y$ is depending on $x$. This is commonly written $y=y(x)$ (i.e. that the number $y$ depends on $x$), and we have the relation $y(x)=7x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

There are these definitions:

Function :
$\forall x\in E,\; \exists^{\leq 1} y\in F,\quad f(x)=y$

Application :
$\forall x\in E, \exists ! y\in F,\quad f(x)=y$

So

$\begin{array}l f:&\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\\& x\to \ln(x)\end{array}$ is a function

$\begin{array}l g:&\mathbb{R}^+_*\to \mathbb{R}\\& x\to \ln(x)\end{array}$ is an application

All applications are functions